# How to do authentication in angular 2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular

I'm going to develop login base system, and wanted to use Auth api with Node + Angular 2.0 + Mongo.

I've checked Auth0, but its paid service.

Is there any way to perform this functionality in Node + Angular 2.0 + Mongo.

Comment: Have you checked Firebase Authentication? https://www.firebase.com/features.html#features-authentication

Comment: Firebase will store information on their server or use their API.

Comment: We need to use open source to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **OAuth 2.0** is the best option for authentication in Node.js.
This library is also available in many other popular languages.

Refer for more details: http://oauth.net/2/

Hope this will help!